# only 1 int being saved using shared preferences

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app, where I have 2 static ints.  I would like to save the value of both of these int, but currently only 1 of the int is being saved.

Here is my code for saving the ints so far:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// The activity is being created.
setContentView(R.layout.durood);


app_preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefscount", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


count = app_preferences.getInt("count", 0);
total = app_preferences.getInt("total", 0);

 @Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("count", count);
editor.putInt("total", total);
editor.commit();
editor.commit();
```

The 'count' int is being saved but not the 'total' int.  Any ideas on how I can rectify this?

edited last bit of code after twaddington's suggestion to:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("count", count);
editor.putInt("total", total);
Log.d("Test", "total: "+total);
editor.commit();
```

My whole code:

```
public class durood extends Activity{

//Count Button
TextView txtCount;
TextView totalCount;
EditText enteramount;
Button btnCount;
Button dmute;
Button dreset;
Button addtotal1;
Button addtotal2;
Button cleartotal;
static int count=0;
static int total=0;
private int x=0;
private int y=0;
private int z=0;
SharedPreferences app_preferences;
MediaPlayer mpButtonClick;
AudioManager audioManager;
public static boolean mutestatus=false;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
// The activity is being created.
setContentView(R.layout.durood);

audioManager =
(AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
//SAVE COUNT
app_preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefscount", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


count = app_preferences.getInt("count", 0);
total = app_preferences.getInt("total", total++);

txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dcount);
txtCount.setText("This app has been started " + count + " times.");

txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dcount);
txtCount.setText("This app has been started " + count + " times.");

enteramount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enteramount);

totalCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalCount);
totalCount.setText("This app has been started " + total + " times.");

txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dcount);

//Button SOUND AND COUNT
mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bubble);

dreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dreset);

cleartotal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cleartotal);

txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dcount);
txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));

totalCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalCount);
totalCount.setText(String.valueOf(total));


btnCount = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dclick);

dmute=(Button)findViewById(R.id.dmute);

addtotal1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addtototal1);
addtotal2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.addtototal2);

btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

count++;
txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
mpButtonClick.start();



}
});

dreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
count = 0;
txtCount.setText("0");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("count", count);
editor.commit();
}
});

cleartotal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
total = 0;
totalCount.setText("0");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("total", total);
editor.commit();

}
});



dmute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
if(!mutestatus){
mutestatus=true;
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);

}
else{
mutestatus=false;
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL );
audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);

}
}});

//add to total 1
addtotal1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

x=Integer.parseInt(txtCount.getText().toString());
y=Integer.parseInt(totalCount.getText().toString());
z=x+y;
totalCount.setText(Integer.toString(z));
count = 0;
txtCount.setText("0");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("count", count);
editor.commit();
}


});

//add to total 2
addtotal2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

x=Integer.parseInt(enteramount.getText().toString());
y=Integer.parseInt(totalCount.getText().toString());
z=x+y;
totalCount.setText(Integer.toString(z));
enteramount.setText("");
}


});
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
// save count value here

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("count", count);
editor.putInt("total", total);
Log.d("Test", "total: "+total);
editor.commit();

mutestatus=false;
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL );
audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
}
```

Comment: you don't have to commit twice btw..

Comment: What populates the total int? You should put in a log statement in onPause to make sure total contains the value you expect. `Log.d(TAG, "Total: "+total);`

Comment: @twaddington the total int is populated by the value of the count int and another edit text field - I have 2 'add to total' buttons, when pressed they add the value to the total int.  I tried adding the log statement above, but I get this error 'TAG cannot be resolved by a variable'.

Comment: `TAG` is just a String constant you can define in your class. You can also replace it with a String value like "Test".

Comment: @twaddington I tried this but the value is still not being saved, see above for the change I made.

Comment: Does the value printed to the log match what you would expect to be saved?

Comment: @twaddington do I get this from the Logcat?  sorry I am new to java

Comment: Yeah, while your device or emulator is connected to your computer, open up a terminal and type `adb logcat` and look for the message.

Comment: @twaddington, hi I got the message when exiting the screen - the total should have been 660 but I got this message in the Logcat: 01-02 21:51:58.893: D/Test(3001): total: 0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22084/discussion-between-mustafa-and-twaddington)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally fixed this issue.  The Int 'total' was being populated by another int 'z' see inn full code above.  I changed this to total as well, and now it is being saved.  Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use MODE_WORLD_READABLE, it's no good and deprecated (since recently but you shouldn't have any reason to do so anyway), try with the default MODE_PRIVATE instead.

Other than that your code should be working fine. Verify the value of total before comitting and that it is an integer. You also don't need to commit twice your editor, once should be enough.

Comment: I made the changes as suggested, but it did not work, same as before.  How do I verify the value of 'total' before commiting?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, use the File Explorer under the DDMS perspective to transfert the file containing the preferences on your computer and examine it.  This file should be located under `/data/data/your_package_name.your_application_name/shared_prefs` .

You must use the `Pull a file from the device` located at the upper right when the focus is on the `File Explorer` tab.